# How can I view the complete changelog for a PPA package?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

When I am viewing a PPA in Launchpad, the "Package Details" view shows me the most recent change from the changelog.  Is there a way to view the entire changelog for a source package in a PPA without downloading the package?

The package browser allows changelog downloads for distribution packages.  It would be quite helpful if I could do this for PPA packages as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/soyuz/+bug/253119) that PPA packages do not show changelog in update-manager

[Have a look at this](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/changelog)

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know about UbuntuUpdates.  The changelog being missing in update-manager isn't what I'm talking about, though; I'm talking about the Launchpad web interface.